# Use property XML comments as parameter descriptions in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, xml-comments

I created a Web API using ASP.NET Core and used swagger to create documentation. I use the XML comments on my API endpoints to provide additional information in the documentation. The swagger configuration is:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "MyAPI.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
```

One of my API endpoints and its XML comments are:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find an existing appointment using the visitor information: First name, last name, email, phone.
    /// </summary>
    /// <url>http://apiurl/api/appointments/appointmentsByVisitor</url>
    /// <param name="criteria">consists of one or more of:  Firstname, lastname, email, phone</param>
    /// <returns>Existing appointment data in an Appointment object or a business error.</returns>
    /// <response code="200">Returns the existing appointment event.</response>
    /// <response code="400">Returns if no parameters are specified.</response>            
    /// <response code="204">Returns if there's no matching appointment.</response>
    /// <response code="500">Returns if there's an unhandled exception.</response>
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("appointmentsByVisitor")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Appointment), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(BusinessError), 404)]
    public IActionResult AppointmentsByVisitor([FromQuery] VisitorSearchCriteria criteria) {}
```

`VisitorSearchCriteria` is a separate class which is a wrapper for the parameters expected by the API endpoint.

```
public class VisitorSearchCriteria
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Visitor first name.
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Visitor last name.
    /// </summary>
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // several other properties....
}
```

The swagger documentation for this API endpoint shows all the properties of VisitorSearchCriteria as parameters, but it doesn't pick the XML comments. See the screenshot below.

[image: Swagger parameter listing]

As you can see, the descriptions of the parameters are missing. How do I tell swagger to use the XML comments from that external class to create parameter descriptions?

Comment: Have you enabled the checkbox for the xml documentation file in the project?

Comment: Yes, the XML comments from the API endpoint are displayed in swagger, only those in that other class are not displayed.

Comment: Are the comments in your MyAPI.xml file? + don't forget to add comment to your class aswell.

Comment: I do have comments in the VisitorSearchCriteria class. But they are not there in the MyAPI.xml file. Only those which are on the controller appear in the xml file.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @GoldenAge: I did not, but I'm going to try what user2534454 mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a model class defined in a different project then you need to go to `Properties` of this project and under the `Build/Output` check the "XML documentation file:" option.
Then you need to update the swagger config file adding.

```
c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\YourProjectName.xml");
```

The YourProjectName.xml should contain the description of your model class fields of course in the XML format.

If you would like to import comments from the different project you need to do the same thing as above, adding

```
c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\YourProjectName2.xml");
```

to the swagger config file.

Keep in mind there can be an XML file generated per project and **you are able to add the comments from all of those files** to your swagger UI.
When you run your Swagger UI the comments should appear in the Model section.

Answer (score 2):

http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/

> First, enable XML documentation file creation during build. In
>   Solution Explorer right-click on the Web API project and click
>   Properties. Click the Build tab and navigate to Output. Make sure XML
>   documentation file is checked. You can leave the default file path. In
>   my case its bin\SwaggerDemoApi.XML

Comment: actually, it's all good. As I mentioned in the question, the XML documentation of the API endpoint is displayed on the documentation. It's the parameter descriptions - which come from a separate class (VisitorSearchCriteria) which are not picked.

Comment: Can  you try this `c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\MyAPI.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));` and see if that works?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I suspects MyAPI.xml doesn't pick the comments from the helper classes, only from the controller?

Comment: Try using this `c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.ChangeExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, "xml"));` instead and make sure your parameter class is in the same assembly as your controller.

Comment: @Lars Skovslund I tried that and it didn't work for me

Comment: @GoldenAge we use the extension method on all our aspnet core 2.2 projects.

`public static void IncludeXmlComments<TFromType>(this SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
            options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.ChangeExtension(typeof(TFromType).Assembly.Location, "xml"));
        }`
Where the generic type is any class residing in the assembly you want to include xml comments from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and found that Swashbuckle will not pick up Xml code comments on parameters no matter what you do.  As a workaround, I use a custom operation filter that looks for named parameters combined with a simple naming convention.  Not perfect, but good enough in most cases:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x => x.OperationFilter<MyParameterFilter>(););
...
public class MyParameterFilter : IOperationFilter {
  public void Appy(OpenApiOperation op, OperationFilterContext context)
  {
    foreach (var parameter in op.Parameters) {
      if (parameter.Name == "xFormat")
         parameter.Description = "Specifies the target format (e.g. 'pdf')";
  }
}
```